Why does this delete function related to single link list doesn't work?
I was recently learning data structures through a singly linked list. When I created all the functions for my list, they all worked fine except for the delete function. flag is the head of the list and stores the number of nodes. flag1 is a representative of flag that doesn't change flag's data value. When I created this function and compared it with others' work, I didn't find much difference. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my logic? I know there might be some other issues that within the code like the the position of return, but it shouldn't be the major problem.
typedef struct Node{
     int data;
     struct Node* next;
}Node;

void delete(Node* flag,int data){
     Node* flag1=flag;
     while(flag1->next){
          Node* preFlag1=flag1;
          flag1=flag1->next;
          if(flag1->data==data){
              preFlag1->next=flag1->next;
              free(flag1);
              flag->data--;
              return;
           }
     }
 }

I tried to ask chatgpt, but the answer is not what I thought was crucial to this problem. I want to know what the problem in the logic aspect.I want them to be pointed out.

It is unclear what is the problem with your function.

Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Why data--? How does this relate to deleting a node?

The problem is that your function gives the caller no way to adjust their head pointer if the original head node happens to have been deleted. In some cases your function updates the flag variable, but this is a local variable, and so the caller will not know about it.
Either you should have the function return the reference to the (possibly different) head node, or the parameter should be a pointer to the head pointer so the function can modify the caller's head pointer.
Other remarks:

Calling a node pointer "flag" is strange. "flag" carries the meaning of a boolean... Just use commonly used names like head, current, previous.
Subtracting from a data field with data-- has little to do with what the function name suggests; this function should just delete a node and not do other things.

Here is code for the two options:
1. Return the pointer
Node* delete(Node* head, int data) {
    Node *previous = NULL;
    Node *current = head;
    while (current && current->data != data) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current) { // Found a node to delete
        if (previous) { // Not the first node
            previous->next = current->next;
        } else {
            head = current->next;
        }
        free(current);
    }
    return head;
}

The caller should take the returned pointer as the head, like so:
head = delete(head, 20);

2. Parameter is a pointer to the head pointer:
void delete(Node** headPtr, int data) {
    Node *previous = NULL;
    Node *current = *headPtr;
    while (current && current->data != data) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current) { // Found a node to delete
        if (previous) { // Not the first node
            previous->next = current->next;
        } else {
            *headPtr = current->next;
        }
        free(current);
    }
}

The caller should pass the address of their head pointer, like so:
delete(&head, 20);


I might be misunderstanding the point, but it seemed to work for me.
Based off of what you said, the head node's data stores the number of following nodes in the list. I think it's odd to have data mean different things based on what node you're referencing, and seems like it will cause a bug.
Delete will scan through all nodes following the head node, delete the first instance of a node with matching data field, and decrement the head node's data (representing number of nodes in list).
I did not rigorously test it, I simply wrote a print_list() function and a small, basic Linked List to see the result of running delete() on it. Example shown below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

// documenting your logic would have helped other readers significantly
void delete(Node* flag,int data){
    Node* flag1=flag;
    while(flag1->next){
      Node* preFlag1=flag1;
      flag1=flag1->next;
      if(flag1->data==data){
          preFlag1->next=flag1->next;
          free(flag1);
          flag->data--;
          return;
       }
    }
}

void print_list(Node* head) {
    Node* ptr = head;
    // print elements of linked list with spaces between
    for(; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%d ", ptr->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    // define head of linked list and pointer to fill it
    Node* head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->data = 4;
    Node* ptr = head;

    // create nodes with ascending value, assigning to linked list
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Node* new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new_ptr->data = i;
        ptr->next = new_ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    print_list(head);
    delete(head, 2);
    print_list(head);
    delete(head, 3);
    print_list(head);
    delete(head, 1);
    print_list(head);
    delete(head, 0);
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}

My output, when running the above, was:

4 0 1 2 3
3 0 1 3
2 0 1
1 0
0

This is exactly what I expected to see, so I am not sure what your issue was. If you could give some explanation on what tests you have run that failed, I could spend my time much more effectively to help.

General overview
Your function is
typedef struct Node{
     int data;
     struct Node* next;
}Node;

void delete(Node* flag,int data){
     Node* flag1=flag;
     while(flag1->next){
          Node* preFlag1=flag1;
          flag1=flag1->next;
          if(flag1->data==data){
              preFlag1->next=flag1->next;
              free(flag1);
              flag->data--;
              return;
           }
     }
 }

and you intend to remove a node from your linked list by data. I am presuming that if there are multiple nodes with the same data, then you want to remove the first such node.
Cases:

your head matches data. In this case:

the head should be saved into a temporary node to avoid losing it due to losing the reference to it
the new head should be set to the next of the old head
the temporary node that represents the item to be removed should be freed


there is a node that matches data. In this case:

that node is to be found with a loop
before you go for the next node in such a loop, you temporarily store your current node so you will be able to set its next (this is why this case will not work if the head matches the data)
when the item is found, then

set the next of the previous node to the next of the current one
free the current node





Data representation
Your list seems to be a list of nodes of descending values, where each node will have a data that equals to the number of nodes starting from the next node until the end of the list.
The problem
You do not treat the removal of the head as a special case. You are doing a loop, you always store temporarily the current node as the prev node, go to the next one and if data is matching, then perform the removal, by setting the next of the prev to the next of the current and freeing the current one.
But this ignores the case when the very first node is the one to be removed.
Also, make sure that if your list is empty, then you just return.
The solution
In your delete function, just before the while loop, check whether the head (flag in this case) is matching data and if so, remove it:
void delete(Node* flag,int data){
     if (!flag) return; //empty list
     if (flag->next == data) {
         Node* temp = flag;
         flag = flag->next;
         free(temp);
         return;
     }
     Node* flag1=flag;
     while(flag1->next){
          Node* preFlag1=flag1;
          flag1=flag1->next;
          if(flag1->data==data){
              preFlag1->next=flag1->next;
              free(flag1);
              flag->data--;
              return;
           }
     }
 }

I do not have a C environment in front of me to test and I have not been working with C for many years, so please take the code above with a grain of salt and let me know if there are any issues you find with it.

Too much text and a very wrong solution.

Lot of thanks for the response. I just figure out that it might be the compiling issue that make everything wrong.

@YiLin what was the compiling issue?
